# installation & configuration of gremlin-neo4j Ubuntu

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I had installed neo4j in my Ubuntu
now i need to configure that neo4j Graph Database to gremlin console.
I need clean installation procedure of gremlin, and configuration of that to Neo4j GDB.
could anyone share me the instructions.

Comment: can you list down all your folder names and versions

Comment: also what all libraries have you installed

Comment: neo4j community 3.3.4 is installed in my ubuntu system.
I have downloaded apache tinkerpop gremlin-server 3.3.2, gremlin-console 3.3.2.
I have extracted both in the documents directory.
Neo4j was installed completely and its working with Cypher Query language.
I need my Neo4j to be used with the gremlin.
How to configure that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Configure Grape as mentioned in [the documentation here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-applications)

Create a new file `~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml` if not already present.

Add the following content:

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="downloadGrapes"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="downloadGrapes">
      <filesystem name="cachedGrapes">
        <ivy pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
        <artifact pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
      </filesystem>
      <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

> The process of plugin installation is handled by Grape, which helps
>   resolve dependencies into the classpath.

2. Install neo4j dependencies on the gremlin server as mentioned in [the documentation here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_configuring_2)

`cd YOUR_SERVER_LOCATION`

`bin/gremlin-server.sh install org.apache.tinkerpop neo4j-gremlin 3.3.3`

You will see then the folder ***neo4j-gremlin*** inside of ***YOUR_SERVER_LOCATION/ext***

2. Start the server

`bin/gremlin-server.sh conf/gremlin-server-neo4j.yaml`